# How to display image on textpane?

Tags: java, image, desktop, jtextpane

I am working on a note taking application which is supposed to include image ,audio ,video along with text 
So im including a feature to add links(like in evernote )which should display an icon on clicking which that file should open
My question is how write to and read from a file so that when a link is encountered an imageicon mus be displayed in textpane similary a link must be written in the file 
I am already able to implement text links i want to know how to do the same with images(image links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `JEditorPane` to use the functionality of both text and Images in java . This would also enable you to add support for custom text formats to the components of your application.

For details Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `JEditorPane`: you might want to check out [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/), which can render XML/XHTML. If you use a suitable XML model internally, you might be able to render your content directly via CSS.